# Can someone can help me with this ruby conditional?

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def palindrome(string)
  string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('') == string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('').reverse
end
```

I need to test my palindrome method using if else
conditions. If the first palindrome returns `true`, I need to print `yes is a palindrome`. If the other palindrome is `false`, I need to print `is not a palindrome. :(`.

With this test code,

```
p palindrome("Dennis, Nell, Edna, Leon, Nedra, Anita, Rolf, Nora, Alice, Carol, Leo, Jane, Reed, Dena, Dale, Basil, Rae, Penny, Lana, Dave, Denny, Lena, Ida, Bernadette, Ben, Ray, Lila, Nina, Jo, Ira, Mara, Sara, Mario, Jan, Ina, Lily, Arne, Bette, Dan, Reba, Diane, Lynn, Ed, Eva, Dana, Lynne, Pearl, Isabel, Ada, Ned, Dee, Rena, Joel, Lora, Cecil, Aaron, Flora, Tina, Arden, Noel, and Ellen sinned.")
p palindrome("Depardieu, go razz a rogue I draped")
p palindrome("Desserts I stressed.")
p palindrome("Detartrated.")
p palindrome("Devo met a Mr., eh, DNA and her mate moved.")
p palindrome("Di as dad said.")
p palindrome("Did I draw Della too tall, Edward? I did?")
p palindrome("Dior droid.")
p palindrome("DNA-land.")
p palindrome("Do geese see god?")
p palindrome("Do good? I? No. Evil anon I deliver. I maim nine more hero-men in Saginaw, sanitary sword a-tuck, Carol, I. Lo! Rack, cut a drowsy rat in Aswan. I gas nine more hero-men in Miami. Reviled, I (Nona) live on. I do, O God.")
p palindrome("abracadabra!")
p palindrome("Mister, mister, on a see-saw with your sister.")
p palindrome("Almost every sentence is NOT a palindrome! How unfair!")
```

I get this output:

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a little function to check if its input is true or false and print the desired line.

```
def is_palindrome(string)
  p palindrome(string) ? "yes is a palindrome" : "is not a palindrome. :("
end

is_palindrome("Depardieu, go razz a rogue I draped")
```

---

That said, there are many very, very good testing libraries for Ruby. I really like [rspec](http://rspec.info/). Here's an example.

```
RSpec.describe "palindrome" do
  it "ignores case" do
    expect( palindrome("Detartrated") ).to be true
  end

  it 'ignores non-alpha numerics' do
    expect( palindrome("DNA-land.") ).to be true
  end

  it 'ignores spaces' do
    expect( palindrome("Dior droid.") ).to be true
  end

  it 'finds non-palindromes' do
    expect( palindrome("abracadabra!") ).to be false
  end
end
```

`gem install rspec` then run it with `rspec`.

```
$ rspec ~/tmp/test.rb
....

Finished in 0.00442 seconds (files took 0.14683 seconds to load)
4 examples, 0 failures
```

This might seem like overkill for one little function, but it will be very important to get familiar with a good testing library as you make more complex creations. It helps organize and describe what scenarios you're testing. And it will give you good information if a test fails.

```
  1) palindrome failed palindrome
     Failure/Error: expect( palindrome("slow speed: deep owls") ).to be true

       expected true
            got false
     # /Users/schwern/tmp/test.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note that `string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('') == string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('').reverse ? 'yes is a palindrome' : ' is not a palindrome. :('` is the same as this:

```
if string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('') == string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('').reverse
'yes is a palindrome'
else
' is not a palindrome. :('
end
```

**Answer:**

```
def palindrome(string)
      string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('') == . 
      string.downcase.split(/\W+/).join('').reverse ? 'yes is a palindrome' : ' is not a palindrome. :('
    end

# test code

p palindrome("Dennis, Nell, Edna, Leon, Nedra, Anita, Rolf, Nora, Alice, Carol, Leo, Jane, Reed, Dena, Dale, Basil, Rae, Penny, Lana, Dave, Denny, Lena, Ida, Bernadette, Ben, Ray, Lila, Nina, Jo, Ira, Mara, Sara, Mario, Jan, Ina, Lily, Arne, Bette, Dan, Reba, Diane, Lynn, Ed, Eva, Dana, Lynne, Pearl, Isabel, Ada, Ned, Dee, Rena, Joel, Lora, Cecil, Aaron, Flora, Tina, Arden, Noel, and Ellen sinned.")
p palindrome("Depardieu, go razz a rogue I draped")
p palindrome("Desserts I stressed.")
p palindrome("Detartrated.")
p palindrome("Devo met a Mr., eh, DNA and her mate moved.")
p palindrome("Di as dad said.")
p palindrome("Did I draw Della too tall, Edward? I did?")
p palindrome("Dior droid.")
p palindrome("DNA-land.")
p palindrome("Do geese see god?")
p palindrome("Do good? I? No. Evil anon I deliver. I maim nine more hero-men in Saginaw, sanitary sword a-tuck, Carol, I. Lo! Rack, cut a drowsy rat in Aswan. I gas nine more hero-men in Miami. Reviled, I (Nona) live on. I do, O God.")
p palindrome("abracadabra!")
p palindrome("Mister, mister, on a see-saw with your sister.")
p palindrome("Almost every sentence is NOT a palindrome! How unfair!")
```

**This will return:**

```
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
"yes is a palindrome"
" is not a palindrome. :("
" is not a palindrome. :("
" is not a palindrome. :("
```